# Creating a database query based on the users input from a form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have an HTML form that lets the user write what they want to search for.  In this case a Name.

The form works, but it's in the php. I don't know what I have to write to get MySQL to search the database for what the user has input.

Here is the line where I get stuck:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE name = 'What do i gonna write
here? (take away the ' ");
```

I'm using PHP 5.

Comment: Is the form method post or get? what is the input name? Do you need help with result output?

Comment: the form method is Post and the input name is : search And yes i need help with the Where Name =   part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you on your way using mysqli. The manual can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

This assumes you are POSTing your form, otherwise you can change $_POST to whatever request variable you'll be using. Some sanity checking on the form variable before or after calling mysqli_real_escape_string would also be very helpful (required) in a production environment.

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","database");

if(mysqli_connect_error())
{
    printf("Connection failed:%s \n",mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['search']);
$table = 'some_table';

if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name = $name", MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // $row is an associative array
        // Do something here
    }
}
$db->close();
```

Comment: Thanks works great but how to output the result in a save way and if result = null part in mysql , thanks man i really appreciate your help and kindness :)

Comment: Your question was how to query the database, not how to output the result. Some research needs to be done on your part.

Answer (score -2):

```
$sf = stripslashes($_REQUEST['search']);
$sf = mysql_real_escape_string($sf);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE name = '". $sf."'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: While this may work this is wildly dangerous and should never, EVER be used as an example. Google SQL injection.

Comment: The question wasnt how to secure from SQL injection, it was how to write the query only. I would (probably stupidly) assume anyone using mysql already knows to strip slashes and all that good stuff.  read the question next time before you give -1

Comment: I would argue that because his question was so basic, he probably doesn't know. On top of that, someone else that knows nothing about PHP may stumble onto this.

Comment: Your disagreeing with my answer is fine, and so is a -1 IF you either a)provide a better example OR b) provide a link to a resource proving why another way should be used rather than using mysql_query.  you are not god and we cannot jut take your word for it

Comment: That's valid, I was in the process of putting up an example.